# Not able to query data between two dates in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date

I am trying to execute a HQL query to fetch data between two dates. The query seems to be correct but i am not able to get the result.Basically i am trying to fetch transaction between two dates.

I am using TimeStamp in the Hibernate entity for transactionDate.
Date object below is from `java.util.Date`.
I am querying between 2016-07-01 to 2016-07-31

Database entries from MySQL:

```
transactionId, academicYear, amount, isActive, period, periodicity, transactionDate, type, studentId
T000000001, 2015-16, 30000, 1, JUN-SEPT, Quarterly, 2016-07-03 11:19:06, Cash, SDT00000001
T000000002, 2015-16, 30000, 1, OCT-JAN, Quarterly, 2016-07-03 11:21:12, Cash, SDT00000001
T000000003, 2015-16, 3670, 1, July, Monthly, 2016-07-03 15:04:31, Cash, SDT00000002
```

Query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from FeesTransactions fs where fs.transactionDate>=:startDate AND "
                        + "fs.transactionDate<=:endDate ORDER BY fs.transactionDate");

query.setParameter("startDate", new Date(TimeConversionHelper.getJodaDate(startDate, "yyyy-mm-dd").getMillis()));
query.setParameter("endDate", new Date(TimeConversionHelper.getJodaDate(endDate, "yyyy-mm-dd").getMillis()));
List<FeesTransactions> transactions = (List)query.list();
```

Any support is well appreciated.

Comment: use between in your query and query.setDate in your code at first.

Comment: Query query = session.createQuery("from FeesTransactions fs where fs.transactionDate  between :startDate AND "
      + ":endDate ORDER BY fs.transactionDate");
                                                                              query.setParameter("startDate", new Date(TimeConversionHelper.getJodaDate(startDate, "yyyy-mm-dd").getMillis()));
                                                                                   query.setParameter("endDate", new Date(TimeConversionHelper.getJodaDate(endDate, "yyyy-mm-dd").getMillis()));

Comment: Used above query also but no result.

Comment: My FeesTransactions entity contains transactionDate like below:          @Column(name="transactionDate")
@Nonnull
private Timestamp transactionDate;